# How to link a template library in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run this github project under Win10:
https://github.com/maxpenner/quadcopter-simulation

And it states:

> Open the project in Visual Studio C++.
>   Two libraries have to be
>   linked:
>
> - Eigen for linear algebra
> - Irrlicht for rendering

As an unexperienced c++ developer, I can't understand how I'm supposed to link these libraries, say Eigen - I downloaded and extracted the Tar file, now what?

Thanks for advance for the help

Comment: In addition to the advice in the duplicate, make absolutely certain that the libraries you downloaded are intended for Visual Studio. Generally Windows doesn't deal in tar files so it's possible you've accidentally grabbed GCC libraries intended for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

After extracting the *Eigen*, add path to its root directory (which contains another `Eigen` directory just inside) to the list of **additional include directories** of the quadcopter-simulation project. (open project properties and find 'additional include directories' option)

For the *Irrlicht*, add path to its include directory to your project's **additional include directories**; and add the `irrlicht.lib` inside `/irrlicht-1.8.4/lib/Win32-visualstudio/` or `/irrlicht-1.8.4/lib/Win64-visualstudio/` to **additional dependencies** of your project.

Comment: Thank you.
I have no object properties, what am I doing wrong? I simply git clone and right click -> open with vs